# Trying to use selection sort on an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, exc-bad-access

I've got an array of structs, and I'm trying to sort it by price using selection sort. I'm consistently getting a ECX_BAD_ACCESS signal.

This is what I've got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

So thing is just a struct with a name and a price. The price is what I want to sort the structs by

```
struct Thing
{
    std::string name;
    double price;
};
```

Right now, the main method just checks to make sure that the sortThing function is working.

```
Thing *sortThing(Thing input[], int size);

int main ()
{
    Thing *stuff = new Thing[3];

    stuff[0].name = "middle";
    stuff[0].price = 2.00;
    stuff[1].name = "last";
    stuff[1].price = 3.00;
    stuff[2].name = "first";
    stuff[2].price = 1.00;

    stuff = sortThing(stuff, 3);

    cout << stuff[0].name + " " + stuff[1].name + " " + stuff[2].name;

    return 0;
}
```

This is where the problem is. It complains about the line where I assign input[maxIndex].name to output[i].name, saying: "Program Received 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'"

```
Thing *sortThing(Thing input[], int size)
{
    Thing *output = new Thing[size];
    Thing nullThing;
    nullThing.name = "&nullThing";
    int min = 0;
    int minIndex;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (input[j].name.compare("&nullThing") != 0 && input[j].price <= min) minIndex = j;
        }
        output[i].name = input[minIndex].name;
        output[i].price = input[minIndex].price;
        input[minIndex] = nullThing;
        minIndex = 0;
        min = 0;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the value of minIndex initially? input[j].price is never less than 0, so minIndex will never be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your loop for determining `minIndex` is incorrect... Since all prices are >= 0, you will never set `minIndex`, and since you never initialized it, it's value can be anything.  Most likely in your case the value is outside the range of the array and effectively having an array out of bounds error.

Might want to look into some sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging 101: here's the first thing to do. Change:

```
int minIndex;
```

to:

```
int minIndex = -42;
```

(temporarily) then output the value of `minIndex` immediately after the inner loop.

This will show you that the value is not being changed.

The *reason* it's not being changed is the initial setting of `min`. Unless you're giving your product away for free, or paying people to take it away, prices will *always* be greater than zero and the second part of the `if` statement will always be false.

Quick fix, set `min` initially to `INT_MAX` (and also where you reset it at the end of the outer loop).

Comment: Yeah. The problem was that min wasn't assigned to anything. I redid some stuff and got it working. Thanks.